# If derivates are equal, does it follow that the function is constant?

Tags: calculus

Suppose $g: [0, \infty) \to \mathbb R^n$ and suppose $g(x) = ( g_1(x),\ldots,g_n(x) ) $.

If we have that for  $ i \neq j$ 
$$g_i'(x) = g_j'(x) $$

then

does it follow that $g$ is constant??

Comment: What about $g(x) = (x,x,x,x,x)$?  Or, depending on your interpretation of "constant", $g(x) = (x+1, x+2, x+3, x+4)$?

Comment: Or, $g(x) = (f(x), f(x), ...f(x)) + (c_1, c_2, ....c_n)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this does not follow. As an example, consider the function $g(x)=(x,x,x,x,x+1,x-927,x+e^{4+\pi})$ in $\mathbb R^7$. Although this function is not constant, the derivatives of the constant functions are equal. However, the function has to be the graph of a line. As @SanathDevalapurkar said, any counterexample has to have every component function be of the form $f(x)+c$, where $c$ is a constant and $f$ is the same for every component.

Answer (score 3):

In general, the counterexamples are of the following form, for a function $f(x)$:
 $$g(x):=(f(x)+c_1,\cdots,f(x)+c_n)$$